# Sci-fi story about a woman observing the progress of technology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a story I found online it was short to mid length.

The story is told from the perspective of a woman. She has a relationship with a man that is involved in technological development and they talk about it. She shows some concern about some of the things he proposes such as a device the size of a coke can that would be able to terraform asteroids.

They don't stay together but she thinks about him sometime and as time progresses new technology comes out that reminds her of the things they talked about. One is a headband that lets you connect more with the internet and then it turns into an implant. Another is some nanotech that helps heal people. Eventually the story progresses and the asteroid-coke-can comes out.

Death is essentially unnecessary at this point so she is out in space at an incredible age and humanity at large doesn’t really use earth anymore. At some point earth gets eaten by the sun expanding and it ends with her preparing to potentially meet the first aliens they encountered.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Comment: Asked about and answered many times:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22The+Gentle+Seduction%22

Comment: If your question is correctly answered you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows in the upper-left corner of the answer.  And you're most welcome.

Comment: @DavidW - If there are multiple duplicates, it's better to select a single target and close them all to that, rather than creating a 'duplicate ring'

Comment: @Valorum I did that.  I pointed all the duplicates here.  Which you know because you changed all of them.

Comment: @DavidW - You had some of them pointing at multiple targets. It's better to choose a single sample answer and then dupe to that, rather than trying to find all the dupes and make a circle; https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK41m.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait, this *is* "[The Gentle Seduction](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48297)" (1989, Marc Stiegler, first published in *Analog*).  I'd completely forgotten the part about terraforming asteroids:

> "Well, with nanotechnology they'll build these tiny little machines—machines the size of molecules." He pointed at the drink in her hand. "They'll put a billion of them in a spaceship the size of a Coke can, and shoot it off to an asteroid. The Coke can will rebuild the asteroid into mansions and palaces. You'll have an asteroid all to yourself, if you want one."

Her friend Jack describes the future of computer interfaces:

> Another time, as they walked in the sun along the beach of Fox Island, he told her more about the future. "You'll have a headband." He ran his fingers across his forehead; he squinted as the wind blew sand in his eyes. "It'll allow you to talk right to your computer."

And then years later she encounters one in real life:

> He was unremarkable for a mountaineer; his lean form supported long straps of hard muscle, and the reflected sun from the glaciers had given him a coffee-colored tan. Then she noticed the sweatband across his head. It was not just a sweatband: she could see from the stretch marks that a series of thin disks ran across within the cotton layers. She realized he was wearing a *nection*, a headband to connect his mind with distant computers.
>
> She recoiled slightly; he smiled and touched his forehead. "Don't be too upset," he said, "my headband just saved your life."

The headband is replaced by a nanotech implant:

> She swallowed one. This capsule was nastier than the others she had taken in earlier years. Before, the nanomachines she had swallowed had gone through her body, fixing what was not right, then flushing themselves out again. But the machines in this one would build, just under her forehead, a subcutaneous nection.

The assemblers rebuilding an asteroid for habitation becomes reality:

> So a small cylinder, somewhat smaller than a Coke can, was launched at an asteroid that had been parked in orbit around Jupiter for this purpose. As the billions of robots from the cylinder swarmed across the asteroid, transforming it into a marvelous home, she boarded another ship.

The Earth doesn't end, at least not in this story; the destruction you recall is probably the eruption of Mount Rainier which is the physical destruction of the land she grew up loving.  But she carries on, and carries its memory forward.

The scope of the story does expand out into the galaxy, though, with the Earth becoming a bit of a backwater.  And eventually there is a meeting with aliens:

> One day two needleships met in space. This was not uncommon; needles from different launchers often crossed paths and were easy to spot, with the hundreds of kilometers of molecular sensor webs they spun.
>
> But this meeting was special, for one of the needles had no link to a human. It belonged to aliens.

Once again our unnamed protagonist is called upon for assistance:

> Then from the contact team she received a Call. They needed her; they needed her elemental resilience and adaptability.

The story ends with her progressing vastly far into the future:

> She dipped much longer still and asked one more time. This time she
> understood. The answer was so simple, so glorious, so joyful, that she did not ask the question again for a billion years.
>
> And by then, it just didn't seem to matter.

You can read the story in the collection [*Nanodreams*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23391) at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/nanodreams0000elli) (free to borrow, registration required).  The story also still appears to be [available to read](http://www.skyhunter.com/marcs/GentleSeduction.html) on the [author's website](http://www.skyhunter.com/marc.html).

Comment: The April 1989 *Analog* can be read at the Luminist archives, no registration needed: https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/SF/AN/AN_1989_04.pdf

Comment: @user14111 The link from your old answer to Stiegler's website still seems to work so I've added that one instead. :)

Comment: Damn, I forgot about that. I see this question has been answered 8 times now.